# Call is ambiguous error using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2008, resharper

First of all, sorry for excesive generic name classes. My employer is paranoid and I know for sure he roams this site. Ok, so I have this code:

```
var fooObj = new MyFooClass()
{
    fooField1 = MyEnum.Value3, 
    fooField2 = false,
    fooField3 = false,
    fooField4 = otherEntity.OneCollection.ElementAt(0) as MyBarClass
}
```

where otherEntity.OneCollection is an ISet. ISet is a NHibernate collection class that implements IEnumerable. If I try to compile this code I get this error:

```
Error 2     The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 
'System.Linq.Enumerable.ElementAt<MyFirm.Blah.Blah.ClassyClass>    (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyFirm.Blah.Blah.ClassyClass>, int)'
and 
'System.Linq.Enumerable.ElementAt<MyFirm.Blah.Blah.ClassyClass>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyFirm.Blah.Blah.ClassyClass>, int)'
```

But if I remove the using System.Linq at the beginning of the class and change the code to this:

```
var fooObj = new MyFooClass()
{
    fooField1 = MyEnum.Value3, 
    fooField2 = false,
    fooField3 = false,
    fooField4 = System.Linq.Enumerable
                     .ElementAt(otherEntity.OneCollection, 0) as MyBarClass
}
```

it compiles and works. (? operator to check if OneCollection has elements removed for the sake of clarity)

Could anyone explain this error to me?

In case is relevant: I'm using Visual Studio 2008, targeting .NET Framework 3.5 and using ReSharper 5.1.

NOTE.- Edited to clarify which concrete IEnumerable is the collection, sorry for that.

Comment: You appear to have referenced 2 versions of `System.Linq.Enumerable<T>`

Comment: have you found a solution? what was the problem? I'm really curious as this is rather uncommon problem

Comment: Yeah. I was completely unable to find the redundant reference of System.Linq.Enumerable, but I was able to go forward doing what I mention on the original question, instead of calling ElementAt as an extension method, I call it like a normal method using its full namespace, ie: System.Linq.Enumerable.ElementAt(collection, index) instead of the much nicer and readable collection.ElementAt(index).

Comment: I ran into this issue when converting from .Net 2.0 (using LinqBridge) to .Net 4.0. The solution, of course, was to remove the reference to LInqBridge

Comment: If you still need to reference LinqBridge then you can use LinqBridge.Embedded instead, which embeds the LinqBridge as a code file instead of as an assembly that gets copied over to the asp.net bin folder and causes conflicts.

Answer (score 4):

This is very strange.

The error claims that there's an ambiguity between two completely identical signatures.

The only thing I can think of is that you might somehow have the 'references' messed up in your project and that maybe you have i.e. reference both to 'System.Core 3.5' and 'System.Core 3.5.0.1' (contrived example).. You would get such error in this case, but yet, I cannot think why `System.Linq.Enumerable.ElementAt(otherEntity.OneCollection` works - it should report the same problem.

.. or maybe you somehow made your 'OneCollection' implement the IEnumerable twice in some wicked way? But then, I think the error message would be different.

Comment: How to check that reference? Its a asp.net website, unable to find reference folder!

Comment: I had the same problem, and when writing `System.Linq.Enumerable`, if I hovered the `Enumerable` part, I got to see the **path** for the two dlls implementing it, so I could get rid of one of them!

Comment: I was trying to refactor a project, by copying the project directory and changing the names manually and only keeping the parts that needed to be shared. Didn't  realize that the original dll was still there and causing this error.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the ambiguous reference, you have to be more explicit. There are two options.

First, you could make your IEnumerable generic, like:

```
IEnumerable<MyFooClass> = new List<MyFooClass>();
...
var fooObj = new MyFooClass()
{
     fooField1 = MyEnum.Value3, 
     fooField2 = false,
     fooField3 = false,
     fooField4 = otherEntity.OneCollection.ElementAt(0) as MyBarClass
 }
```

Or second; if it's a non-generic IEnumerable, do a cast:

```
IEnumerable = new List<MyFooClass>();
...
var fooObj = new MyFooClass()
{
     fooField1 = MyEnum.Value3, 
     fooField2 = false,
     fooField3 = false,
     fooField4 = otherEntity.OneCollection.Cast<MyFooClass>().ElementAt(0)
 }
```

Comment: How does that answer the question? didn't get it..He said "Linq" functions aren't identified due to ambiguous call