# Clueless about removing a duplicate reference

Tags: c#, linq, resharper

This is related to this question: [Call is ambiguous error using Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874197/call-is-ambiguous-error-using-linq)

Same project, same errors. Everytime I try to use an extension method from Linq I get an error about an ambiguous reference. For example;

```
listOfThings.Where(x => x.Foo == 1);
```

doesn't compile and returns the error, while

```
System.Linq.Enumerable.Where(listOfThings, x => x.Foo == 1);
```

runs OK. Besides, when I write System.Linq... I see on Resharper's Intellisense TWO references to System.Linq; number one:

[image: R# Intellisense 1]

and number two:

[image]

Can anyone help me trace the duplicated reference? Any place I could look? Any tool I could use? Thanks!

Comment: Post up the assembly references you have.

Comment: One is a reference to the C# class the other is a reference to the VB.Net you don't actually have duplicate references.  **Update your question with the actual error you recieve.**

Comment: @Ramhound I don't think there is anything related to VB.net here. The message in the second screenshot is the standard description of the `Enumerable` class. It only mentions VB because it uses the keyword `shared` instead of `static`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - The screenshot says otherwise.  I could of course be wrong but its very strange that System.Linq.Enumerable contain the phrase **Shared in Visual Basic** if I wasn't at least partially correct.

Comment: No, the SS says that static fields in C# are called Shared in Visual Basic. Nothing remotely related to Visual Basic on my solution, it's not even installed.

Comment: Can you post your references?

Comment: No, sorry. There is some propietary information in there, such as the name of my current company (I'm a contractor) and I know for a fact my boss roams here...

Answer (score 1):

*This is not necessarily the answer, but the steps are too complex to put in a comment.*

**Update**

A few more things to try:

First try running visual studio in [safe mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Verify the issue is not caused by a plugin.

1. See if the issue exists on other machines with this project
2. [Reinstall](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21) the 3.5 .NET framework (sounds like you are using v3.5)
3. See what's in the GAC:
   In visual sstudio command prompt run `gacutil /l > C:\gac.txt`.  Check this file's contents for System.Core.  For .NET 3.5 I have one System.Core which looks like:

`System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL`

I have one more for v4.0.  I also have .NET 4.5 installed.  For whatever reason this did not add a new System.Core.dll to my machine (according to MSDN System.Core.dll still contains System.LINQ in v4.5).

---

Please open open the project and show us the MSBUILD.  You will be looking for System.Core which is the assembly that contains System.LINQ.

1. Right click the project > Choose "Unload Project" > Right click project again this time choose "Edit (ProjectName)".
2. Now look for references to System.Core.  How many do you have?  Does it look like:

   `<Reference Include="System.Core" />`
3. Remove any duplicate references to System.Core.
4. Reload the project. If the problem still exists...
5. remove the reference to System.Core. Re-add the reference through the Assemblies > Framework tab (or .NET tab I believe prior to VS 2012).
6. Re-check the MSBuild by starting at step 1 and if the issue still exists please post the MSBuild of the reference along with the PATH and RUNTIME VERSION available in Properties for the assembly in the references folder.

Comment: It's only referenced one, like this:      <Reference Include="System.Core">
      <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
    </Reference>

Comment: @Picacodigos - Did you try the other steps?  What is the PATH?

Comment: Yeah, I did the load and reload of the project several times and examined the XML, nothing strange there. If you're asking for the Reference Paths tab of the project's properties, is empty. The target runtime is .NET 3.5.

Comment: @Picacodigos - You may have a bad installation of the .NET framework on the machine. Can you reproduce the issue on another machine? Also see updates, particularly safemode.

Comment: 1) Running VS in safe mode -> Same issue when compiling, although the double reference in Intellisense (as seen in the pictures above) disappears... 2) Only one System.Core on my generated gac.txt and it's exactly the same as yours. 3) Couldn't reinstall NET framework, sorry, corporate restrictions and all that. :( Last but not least, THANKS for your efforts, Brian, they're surely appreciated.

Comment: @Picacodigos - I recommend you try the code on another machine.  And likely...request a reinstall of the .NET framework from the employer.  Visual Studio should be run in administrative mode (I've experienced many problems otherwise).  I would also request admin rights as a necessary factor to do your job.  I'm not an HR person however I do know that as a contractor the employer should not be controlling your environment or providing you equipment, but that's a whole new and different type of problem.